# How to use $push inside $set in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using [`express-restify-mongoose`](https://github.com/florianholzapfel/express-restify-mongoose) library to have rest endpoints agaist mongoose.

I have schema looks like this:

```
const BookSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    items: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }],
  }
);
```

So I send http patch request: `{ name: 'blabla' }` and it change the name as expect.

But when I want to add item to items array like `{ items: ["5dd138199f6ecb3990360328"] }` its replace the entire object (with one `5dd138199f6ecb399036032d` item).

After I digging in the source code [I see here](https://github.com/florianholzapfel/express-restify-mongoose/blob/37f1803d584f6ffcbcbd7d8b5ae74ad08c403aeb/src/operations.js#L235) the function uses `findOneAndUpdate` and `$set`.

So my question is there is any way to use `$push` or any function/property in the `$set` value?

I can't add to this library, but maybe there is any workaround solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest solution in mongoose is to use [Set Elements in Arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

```
"items.1": "5dd138199f6ecb3990360355"
```

Which will add to array, but you have to pass the position.

Comment: Nice. how about delete?